# How I can set a 'limit' of alerts on sensu?

Tags: sensu

I wish to set a limit of alerts from sensu. For instance, after 5 alerts from host X about disk capacity, I would like to stop receive alerts about the same issue.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with sensu [filters](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/filters). 
Something like:

```
{
  "filters": {
    "firstfive": {
      "attributes": {
        "occurrences": "eval: value <= 5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You need to add such filter to the [handler](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/handlers) you have created for the email.

Comment: So, just to add on above question, how can we apply this filter specifically on an event called say event.name = 'check_disc'?